# Test all Object have specific property or not by every()

Tags: javascript

This is my Object

```js
var MyObject =[{
  first: "Romeo",
  last: "Montague"
}, {
  first: "Mercutio",
  last: null
}];
```

And this is target property:

```js
var Target = {
  last: "Capulet"
};
```

I want to find out all Object  have the target property or not. And from my object and target property above expected result is **True** because both of them have **'last'** property

Function to find object:

```js
function Find(obj,source){
  const key = Object.keys(source);

  console.log(obj.every(keys => obj.hasOwnProperty(key))); /* false*/
  console.log(obj[0].hasOwnProperty(key));/*true*/
  console.log(obj[1].hasOwnProperty(key));/*true*/
}
```

I don't understand why  `console.log(obj.every(keys => obj.hasOwnProperty(key)));` returns `false` but   `console.log(obj[0].hasOwnProperty(key))` and  `console.log(obj[1].hasOwnProperty(key))` return `true`.

Comment: Instead of `hasOwnProperty`, it's far easier to just directly test for the key/value. Also, remember to use JS naming conventions: variables and functions user lowerCamelCase, only classes use UpperCamelCase.

Comment: Also the function is incorrect; the `key` variable is incorrect, as `key` will be an *array* of keys, not one key. You get an individual key as the parameter to the `.every()` callback. For your purposes, `key => key in obj` would be a lot simpler (as the `.every()` callback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo here:

```
function Find(obj,source){
  const key = Object.keys(source);

  console.log(obj.every(keys => obj.hasOwnProperty(key)));
//                      ^^^^    ^^^
  console.log(obj[0].hasOwnProperty(key));/*true*/
  console.log(obj[1].hasOwnProperty(key));/*true*/
}
```

Your `every` callback is declaring a parameter named `keys`, which you are not using, instead you call `hasOwnProperty` on the `obj` array again (which indeed does not have the `key` property).

Name your variables properly, using plural for things that are arrays, and use only the first of the `Object.keys(…)` as the `key` (you were using a single-element array, which was weird but worked because it was coerced to a string). Corrected:

```
function find(objects, source) {
  const key = Object.keys(source)[0];
//                               ^^^
  return objects.every(obj => Object.hasOwn(obj, key));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Split your problem into smaller, composable, parts:

1. given a property and its value, check if an object has that property, or even has that property with that exact value.
2. given that functionality, check a list of objects all in the same way
3. given that functionality, check a list of objects for any number of key/value properties.

The first is easy enough:

```js
function checkEntry(entry, propName, value) {
  const found = entry[propName];
  return found !== undefined && found !== null;
  /*
    or "return !!found" if "falsey" values like 0 or "" should be false, too,
    or even "return found && found === value" if we need strict value agreement,
    or use entry.hasOwnProperty here, but you're not showing a prototyped object,
    so there's not much point in getting that low-level.
  */
}
```

The second is then just a matter of wrapping that in an `every` for our data list:

```js
function checkList(dataList, propName, value) {
  return dataList.every((entry) => checkEntry(entry, propName, value));
}
```

And the third is then just a matter of wrapping *that* in another `every` for our required properties:

```js
function checkListForRequirements(datalist, requiredProperties) {
  return Object.entries(requiredProperties).every(([propName, value]) =>
    checkList(datalist, propName, value)
  );
}
```

Now that we know the composition, we can put it all together into a single function and run it on our data:

```js
function checkListForRequirements(dataList, requiredProperties) {
  return Object.entries(requiredProperties).every(([propName, value]) =>
    dataList.every((entry) => entry[propName] ?? false)
  );
}

const data = [
  {
    first: "Romeo",
    last: "Montague",
  },
  {
    first: "Mercutio",
    last: null,
  },
];

const requiredProperties = {
  last: "Capulet",
};

console.log(checkListForRequirements(data, requiredProperties)); 

const moreData = [
  {
    first: "Romeo",
    last: "Montague",
  },
  {
    first: "Mercutio",
    last: "Capulet",
  },
];

console.log(checkListForRequirements(moreData, requiredProperties));
```

Comment: the OP doesn't need to compare values

Comment: Then the op has loads of options now because removing `entry[propName] === value` is trivial: the `checkEntry` step is what matters, whether we're comparing values or merely checking for the prop's existence. But that's up to them to comment on.

Comment: it's wrong now, the first test case should return `true`

Comment: If a property being the value `null` is considered "existing", that's not a good thing (it's why we even have a nullish operator). So I'll let them sort that out. They've been giving plenty of information to do so here.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some flaws:

```
const key = Object.keys(source);
console.log(obj.every(keys => obj.hasOwnProperty(key)));
```

1. `key` is an array of property names not a property name, use `const [key] = Object.keys(source);`
2. `obj.hasOwnProperty` refers to `MyObject` array, it should be `keys`. But `keys` argument name is misleading, use something like `item`:

```
console.log(obj.every(item=> item.hasOwnProperty(key)));
```

The solutions:

Here is a generic solution for any number of properties in `Target`. We use the second `Array::every()` here to ensure that every property in `Target` is `MyObject`'s item:

```js
const keys = Object.keys(Target);
const result = MyObject.every((item, count) => keys.every(key => key in item));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
var MyObject =[{
  first: "Romeo",
  last: "Montague"
}, {
  first: "Mercutio",
  last: null
}];
var Target = {
  last: "Capulet",
  first: "TEST"
};
</script>
```

For only the first property I would use `in` operator since it seems the fastest:

```js
const [key] = Object.keys(Target);
const result = MyObject.every(obj => key in obj);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
var MyObject =[{
  first: "Romeo",
  last: "Montague"
}, {
  first: "Mercutio",
  last: null
}];
var Target = {
  last: "Capulet"
};
</script>
```

And a benchmark:

```
Cycles: 1000
-------------------------------------------------------------
Alexander one property   :  100(min)  117  133  130  100  101
Alexander all properties :  113(min)  113  140  144  113  144
Pomax                    :  166(min)  166  200  174  176  182
-------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark
```

```html
<script benchmark="1000">

    const chunk = [{
      first: "Romeo",
      second: "Dummy",
      third: "Dummy",
      fourth: "Dummy",
      last: "Montague",
    }, {
      first: "Mercutio",
      second: "Dummy",
      third: "Dummy",
      fourth: "Dummy",
      last: null
    }];

    const MyObject = [];
    
    let count = 10000;
    while(count--) MyObject.push(...structuredClone(chunk));
    
    var Target = {
      last: "Capulet"
    };

// @benchmark Pomax

function find(objects, source) {
  const key = Object.keys(source)[0];
  return objects.every(obj => Object.hasOwn(obj, key));
}

// @run
find(MyObject, Target);

// @benchmark Alexander one property

const [key] = Object.keys(Target);
MyObject.every(obj => key in obj);


// @benchmark Alexander all properties

const keys = Object.keys(Target);
MyObject.every((item, count) => keys.every(key => key in item));

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: You know that readable code is almost always better than "performant" code, right? You don't have to benchmark, and optimize everything prematurely. Maybe this code will be run once every day. Also, what's performant in the browser (where you do your benchmarks) may not be the fastest in other runtimes (e.g. Node.js)

Comment: @Drarig29 what's wrong about readability here?

Comment: @Drarig29 writing beautiful code like functional and spreads with array method chaining and so on loses a millisecond here and there, given a big amount of code working in modern frontends you could end up with a button component rendering 100ms on an upper middle smartphone. i see many big sites not usable on mobile devices and mediocre desktops. the last awful experience was with Vuetify.

Comment: Well, your updated answer is better, but you once had `MyObject.every((item, count) => (count = 0, Object.keys(item).some(k => keys.length === (count += k in Target));`. And this was over-complicated code for something you can write as your "one property" or "all properties" solutions.

Comment: @Drarig29 it was awful and moreover stupid, agree

Comment: @Drarig29 regarding performance, it's always possible to make performant code more readable